# Can't install ccxt package becouse of pycares error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, ccxt

I am using python 3.9.2.
I wanted to install *ccxt* package in a virtual environment I have created

```
python3 -m venv venv_cryptofolio
```

and I encountered an error, which I'm posting below (but not in full, because it's too big compared to the problem description and stack overflow doesn't allow me to post it):

```
build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9/_cares.c:2682:55: error: too many arguments to function call, expected 6, have 7
  return ares_parse_ptr_reply(x0, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6);
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                         ^~
/usr/local/include/ares.h:653:14: note: 'ares_parse_ptr_reply' declared here
CARES_EXTERN int ares_parse_ptr_reply(const unsigned char *abuf,
             ^
build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9/_cares.c:2760:59: error: too many arguments to function call, expected 6, have 7
  { result = ares_parse_ptr_reply(x0, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6); }
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                         ^~
/usr/local/include/ares.h:653:14: note: 'ares_parse_ptr_reply' declared here
CARES_EXTERN int ares_parse_ptr_reply(const unsigned char *abuf,
             ^
build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9/_cares.c:4403:14: error: no member named 'ttl' in 'struct ares_mx_reply'
  (void)((p->ttl) | 0);  /* check that 'struct ares_mx_reply.ttl' is an integer */
          ~  ^
build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9/_cares.c:4419:14: error: no member named 'ttl' in 'struct ares_naptr_reply'
  (void)((p->ttl) | 0);  /* check that 'struct ares_naptr_reply.ttl' is an integer */
          ~  ^
build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9/_cares.c:4459:14: error: no member named 'ttl' in 'struct ares_soa_reply'
  (void)((p->ttl) | 0);  /* check that 'struct ares_soa_reply.ttl' is an integer */
          ~  ^
build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9/_cares.c:4473:14: error: no member named 'ttl' in 'struct ares_srv_reply'
  (void)((p->ttl) | 0);  /* check that 'struct ares_srv_reply.ttl' is an integer */
          ~  ^
build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9/_cares.c:4486:14: error: no member named 'ttl' in 'struct ares_txt_ext'
  (void)((p->ttl) | 0);  /* check that 'struct ares_txt_ext.ttl' is an integer */
          ~  ^
build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9/_cares.c:4498:14: error: no member named 'ttl' in 'struct ares_txt_reply'
  (void)((p->ttl) | 0);  /* check that 'struct ares_txt_reply.ttl' is an integer */
          ~  ^
build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9/_cares.c:4757:12: error: no member named 'ttl' in 'ares_mx_reply'
  { "ttl", offsetof(struct ares_mx_reply, ttl),
           ^                              ~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/10.0.1/include/stddef.h:120:24: note: expanded from macro 'offsetof'
#define offsetof(t, d) __builtin_offsetof(t, d)
                       ^                     ~
build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9/_cares.c:4758:48: error: no member named 'ttl' in 'struct ares_mx_reply'
           sizeof(((struct ares_mx_reply *)0)->ttl),
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9/_cares.c:4781:12: error: no member named 'ttl' in 'ares_naptr_reply'
  { "ttl", offsetof(struct ares_naptr_reply, ttl),
           ^                                 ~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/10.0.1/include/stddef.h:120:24: note: expanded from macro 'offsetof'
#define offsetof(t, d) __builtin_offsetof(t, d)
                       ^                     ~
build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9/_cares.c:4782:51: error: no member named 'ttl' in 'struct ares_naptr_reply'
           sizeof(((struct ares_naptr_reply *)0)->ttl),
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9/_cares.c:4853:12: error: no member named 'ttl' in 'ares_soa_reply'
  { "ttl", offsetof(struct ares_soa_reply, ttl),
           ^                               ~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/10.0.1/include/stddef.h:120:24: note: expanded from macro 'offsetof'
#define offsetof(t, d) __builtin_offsetof(t, d)
                       ^                     ~
build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9/_cares.c:4854:49: error: no member named 'ttl' in 'struct ares_soa_reply'
           sizeof(((struct ares_soa_reply *)0)->ttl),
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9/_cares.c:4871:12: error: no member named 'ttl' in 'ares_srv_reply'
  { "ttl", offsetof(struct ares_srv_reply, ttl),
           ^                               ~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/10.0.1/include/stddef.h:120:24: note: expanded from macro 'offsetof'
#define offsetof(t, d) __builtin_offsetof(t, d)
                       ^                     ~
build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9/_cares.c:4872:49: error: no member named 'ttl' in 'struct ares_srv_reply'
           sizeof(((struct ares_srv_reply *)0)->ttl),
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9/_cares.c:4886:12: error: no member named 'ttl' in 'ares_txt_ext'
  { "ttl", offsetof(struct ares_txt_ext, ttl),
           ^                             ~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/10.0.1/include/stddef.h:120:24: note: expanded from macro 'offsetof'
#define offsetof(t, d) __builtin_offsetof(t, d)
                       ^                     ~
build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9/_cares.c:4887:47: error: no member named 'ttl' in 'struct ares_txt_ext'
           sizeof(((struct ares_txt_ext *)0)->ttl),
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9/_cares.c:4898:12: error: no member named 'ttl' in 'ares_txt_reply'
  { "ttl", offsetof(struct ares_txt_reply, ttl),
           ^                               ~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/10.0.1/include/stddef.h:120:24: note: expanded from macro 'offsetof'
#define offsetof(t, d) __builtin_offsetof(t, d)
                       ^                     ~
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
```

I tried to reinstall *pycares* using the command:

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pycares
```

and as a result I got a similar error, which I will publish here if needed.

What is the cause of this and what is the solution?

EDIT:

I found the solution which is deleting *cares* files:

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies c-ares
```

This is the resource that helped me figuring out the solution:

https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/issues/4798

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found and answer which I posted at the bottom of question itself.